# How can I cyclically remove entries from my database?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, relational-database

I have a table used to store some entries with a date, which I put in a "datetime" typed field.
I'd like to automatically move those entries at that time to another table.
The result would be having a table with all the passed entries, and one with the future ones.

I was thinking about using a stored procedure, but I wouldn't know how to trigger them when I want.
Or maybe I need a standalone application always running on my server.
Or maybe I'm just not thinking to the right, banal solution...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers *events*, which are like stored procedures but also run at a particular time or on a particular schedule.

The basic sequence of queries to do what you want is this.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @time := NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
INSERT INTO archive_log
SELECT * 
  FROM live_log
 WHERE  timestamp <= @time;
DELETE FROM live_log WHERE timestamp <= @time;
COMMIT;
```

You'll run this as often as you need to. Each time you run it you'll move old records from the `live_log` table to the `archive_log` table. The phrase `- INTERVAL 24 HOUR` governs how old the records must be to move them.

You can run this as a MySQL event. For this to work event scheduling must be on in your MySQL server. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html

Here's how you declare this event.

```
CREATE EVENT `archiver` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 4 HOUR
    STARTS '2015-05-23 15:11:23'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO 
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    SET @time := NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
    INSERT INTO archive_log
    SELECT * 
      FROM live_log
     WHERE  timestamp <= @time;
    DELETE FROM live_log WHERE timestamp <= @time;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Notice that the query is embedded in the `CREATE EVENT` code. Debug the query first, before you put it into the event, because debugging events is hard.